# react redux two components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that will display the products which is coming from backend and a component that receives the products to filter but I have doubt that receive by redux my product list.

should i put for my filters component receive?
or should return the same as I get in my product component?
or should I create an action to filter what I need already?

my home:

```
    return (
      <div className="container">
      <h1>Shopping</h1>
      <hr />
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3"><Filters/></div>
        <div className="col-md-9"><Products/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

my component products:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { ProductsFetchData } from '../../store/actions/productsFetch';
import util from '../../util';
class HomeProducts extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('/products');
      }
    render() {
      const productItems = this.props.products.map( product => (
          <div className="col-md-4 pt-4 pl-2">
          <div className = "thumbnail text-center"> 
          <a href={`#${product.id}`}  onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>
              <p>
                  {product.name}
              </p>
          </a>
          </div>
              <b>{util.formatCurrency(product.price)}</b>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
      )
      )
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {productItems}
            </div>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        products: state.Products,
        hasErrored: state.ProductsHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.ProductsIsLoading
    };
  };
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: () => dispatch(ProductsFetchData())
    };
  };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeProducts);
```

my components filter

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css'
class FilterHome extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className="filterbt btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Filters</button>

                    <div className=" mt-4 d-flex flex-column">

                        <p className="textCategory">CATEGORY</p>
                        <div className="category d-flex flex-column">
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Stat Trak</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Normal</p></a>
                        </div>

                        <p className="textCategory">EXTERIOR</p>
                        <div className="category d-flex flex-column">
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Factory New ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Minimal Wear ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Field Tested ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Well Worn ()</p></a>
                            <a href="" className="text-decoration-none"><p>Battle Scarred ()</p></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default FilterHome;
```

Comment: i don't quite understand, filter component doesn't hold any data or no handles or callbacks. comment what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: yes at first there's no cause I don't know the best way

I make a call with my api in component product

and I need these products in my component filter, but I don't know what is the best thing to do, make an action already filtered or I don't know

Comment: basically in my filter component, I need to filter products that are in a certain category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.**redux-state**: this is the registering point for all your api responses(all the data from back-end is stored here as prestine and is available as props to any container when you mapStateToProps).

2.**local-state**: this lives only in your container and all it's child components.

3.**filter**:

a)**from server**:

you make a request to the server and get a response of filtered products. this 
  is more practical.
  eg: you have */products?page=1* and you want to search it by some category, let's 
    say by a specific company. with the data you have at the moment(page 1), you 
  may have only let's say 1 or even no product relevant to that company, but in fact there are n-numbers  of products of the same company available at the server. so this can only be   assumed as the 
  most practical way.

b)**filtering from the local-state**:

if this is what your'e trying to achieve,
1. you need only one container, HomeProducts
2. make ProductItems as a component. wer'e gonna reuse this component to render both.

**you wrote your filter as an independent container. but those filter functionality should be availabe inside the home page itself. isn't it, i mean you're filtering from the home page itself not from another page. if so, add it to the home page itself

**1.HomePage**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { ProductsFetchData } from '../../store/actions/productsFetch';
import util from '../../util';
import ProductItems from '<<..your relative path>>'
import FilterHome from '<<..your relative path>>'


class HomeProducts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        productList: null,
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //this.props.fetchData('/products');
        this.props.fetchData('page=1');
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      const { productList } = this.state
      const { products } = this.props

      // this only handles when local state is empty. add your logic here..
      !productList && this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        productList: products,
      }))
    }

    handleFilter = (category) => {
      // if it's an api call
      const { fetchData }  = this.props
      fetchData(`page=1&category=${category}`)

      //or you simply want to filter this local state(not-recommended)
      const { products } = this.props
      const productsList = [...products].filter(item => item.category === category)

      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        productsList,
      }))
    }

    render() {
      const { productList } = this.state
      const { handleFilter } = this

      return (
          <div className="container">

            <FilterHome {...{ handleFilter }} />

            <ProductItems {...{ productsList }} />
          </div>
      )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    products: state.Products,
    hasErrored: state.ProductsHasErrored,
    isLoading: state.ProductsIsLoading
  };
};

//it may not suit depends on your api, but you get the idea..
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    // fetchData: () => dispatch(ProductsFetchData())
    fetchData: params => dispatch(ProductsFetchData(`/products?${params}`))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeProducts);
```

**2.ProductItems**

```
import React from 'react'

const ProductItem = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-4 pt-4 pl-2">
      <div className = "thumbnail text-center"> 
      <a href={`#${product.id}`}  onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>
          <p>
              {product.name}
          </p>
      </a>
      </div>
      <b>{util.formatCurrency(product.price)}</b>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const ProductItems = ({ productList }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">      
      {productList && productList.map(product => <ProductItem key={product.id} {...{ product }} />)}  
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductItems
```

3.FilterHome

```
import React from 'react'

const FilterHome = ({ handleFilter }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <button className="filterbt btn btn-danger btn-rounded">Filters</button>

      <div className=" mt-4 d-flex flex-column">

        <p className="textCategory">CATEGORY</p>
        <div className="category d-flex flex-column">
          <a href="" className="text-decoration-none" onClick={() => handleFilter('stat_trak')}><p>Stat Trak</p></a>
          <a href="" className="text-decoration-none" onClick={() => handleFilter('normal')}><p>Normal</p></a>
        </div>

        <p className="textCategory">EXTERIOR</p>
        <div className="category d-flex flex-column">
          <a href="" className="text-decoration-none" onClick={() => handleFilter('factory_new')}><p>Factory New ()</p></a>
          <a href="" className="text-decoration-none" onClick={() => handleFilter('minimal_wear')}><p>Minimal Wear ()</p></a>
          <a href="" className="text-decoration-none" onClick={() => handleFilter('field_tested')}><p>Field Tested ()</p></a>
          <a href="" className="text-decoration-none" onClick={() => handleFilter('well_worn')}><p>Well Worn ()</p></a>
          <a href="" className="text-decoration-none" onClick={() => handleFilter('battle_scarred')}><p>Battle Scarred ()</p></a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FilterHome
```

i roughly re-wrote it, may contain bugs..

Answer (score 0):

first add it to the local state and employ a call back to the filter component..

```
handleFilter = (category) => {
 const { Products } = this.state
 const products = {...Products}
 //or depends on the type, so it wont mutate the real data>> const products = [...Products]

 return products.filter(item => item.category === category)
}
```

this is what is understood from your comment. is that it?

Comment: I don't quite understand where to put this in my container products or filter?

Comment: Basically I have two containers, clicking on my filter I will call an action where I will put the products of this category in my product container, 
I got a little confused where and how it would work